# cannot initialize zlib deflate Z_VERSION_ERROR

Tags: gcc, zlib

When I try to initialize a zlib stream to compress some data I get Z_VERSION_ERROR returned. The manual says Z_VERSION_ERROR is returned "if the zlib library version is incompatible with the version assumed by the caller". I have no idea how to resolve this, there seems to only be one version of zlib on my system.

example code

```
#include "zlib.h"

...

printf("VERSION %s\n", ZLIB_VERSION);

int rc = 0;
z_stream strm;
strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
rc = deflateInit(&strm, -1);

if(rc != Z_OK){
    printf("Error %d\n", rc);
    return;
}
```

returns

```
VERSION 1.2.8
Error -6
```

The example program zpipe.c has comments that mention Z_VERSION_ERROR is returned "if the version of zlib.h and the version of the library linked do not match", so i checked the linked version and the zlib.h file, they both say 1.2.8.

ldd

```
ldd output
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007fe9b4c5c000)
...
```

libz.so.1 is a symbolic link

```
file /usr/lib/libz.so.1
/usr/lib/libz.so.1: symbolic link to libz.so.1.2.8
```

zlib.h

```
cat /usr/include/zlib.h |grep ZLIB_VERSION
#define ZLIB_VERSION "1.2.8"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also occur if the size of the z_stream structure made in the C program using the description in zlib.h does not match the size of the compiled z_stream structure libz.so.1.

Is there more than one way to compile programs on your machine that changes the size of any data types, such as integers or pointers?

Comment: I've found a solution, I don't get whats going on exactly but elsewhere in my source the assimp library was included and it also depends on zlib, #including zlib.h wherever assimp was included fixed the Z_VERSION_ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on OSX (Xcode 10) by replacing the old Linked Framework and Libraries entry `libz.dylib` with the newer `libz.tbd`.